# travelling salesman

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to program TSP problem in R. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) page section "Integer linear programming formulation", I was able to understand all the constraints except the last one.

Need help to understand the last constraint...what are the variable U/artificial varaibles? are they slack variables for earlier constraints?